# Animation works good down and doesnt work go up

Tags: javascript, animation

I am looking for way to make all pages move left,right,top,down.
Everithig is ok with down, but part up doesnt work well. I put all pages in a big container. I use three smaller containers(display flex). I hidden all pages. Only one we can see. When we move down and up we see fist child of next(last)container. When we move on sides(haven't done yet)we move to nextSubline.Part down woks. But put up show me every time fist chid fist container and after go up to white space. Is any ideas why it happenes? Maybe you can give me advaice how better to realise this.

```js
var down = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-arrow-down");
// var container= document.getElementsByClassName("container");
for (var i = 0; i < down.length; i++) {
    down[i].onclick = function showNext(){
        var parent = this.parentElement;
        var ourCont=parent.parentElement;
        var nextCont=ourCont.nextElementSibling;
        var pageToShow=nextCont.firstElementChild;
        var contToMove=ourCont.parentElement;
        
        contToMove.addEventListener('animationend', () => {            
            contToMove.classList.remove('page-moveUp');
            parent.classList.remove('page-visible');
        });
              
        pageToShow.classList.add('page-visible');
        contToMove.classList.add('page-moveUp');
        
    }
}

var up = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-arrow-up");

for (var i = 0; i < up.length; i++) {
    up[i].onclick = function showLast(){        
        var parent = this.parentElement;
        var ourCont=parent.parentElement;
        var lastCont=ourCont.previousElementSibling;
        var pageToShow=lastCont.firstElementChild;
        var contToMove=ourCont.parentElement;
        
      
      
        contToMove.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
        contToMove.classList.remove('page-moveDown');
        parent.classList.remove('page-visible');
        
      });
      pageToShow.classList.add('page-visible');
      contToMove.classList.add('page-moveDown');   
    
              
    }
    
    
     
}
```

```css
body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    
}

.container{   
    display: flex;   
}
.page{  
    min-width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100vh; 
    position: relative;  
    display: none;
}
.page-visible {
    display: block;
  }
.q{
    background:purple;
}
.a{
    background:orange;
}
.z{
    background:red;
}
.w{
    background:brown;
}
.s{
    background:green;
}
.x{
    background:gray;
}
.e{
    background:rgb(42, 165, 83);
}
.d{
    background:rgb(91, 139, 91);
}
.c{
    background:rgb(168, 37, 37);
}
.page-moveUp {
    animation: moveUp 3s ease both;
  }
  @keyframes moveUp {
 from {top:0px }
 to {transform: translateY(-100vh); }
}
.page-moveDown{
    animation: moveDown 10s ease both;
}
@keyframes moveDown {
 from{top:100vh }
 to {transform: translateY(100vh); }
}
.up{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 47%;  
}
.down{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50px;
    left: 47%;
}
.left{
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 50px;

}
.right{
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;;
    right: 50px;  

}
span{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="super-container">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page q page-visible">
            <span class="up btn-arrow-up">up</span>
            <span class="left btn-arrow-left">left</span>
            <span class="right btn-arrow-right">right</span>
            <span class="down  btn-arrow-down">down</span>
        </div>
        <div class="page a">
                <span class="up btn-arrow-up">up</span>
                <span class="left btn-arrow-left">left</span>
                <span class="right btn-arrow-right">right</span>
                <span class="down  btn-arrow-down">down</span>
        </div>
        <div class="page z">
                <span class="up btn-arrow-up">up</span>
                <span class="left btn-arrow-left">left</span>
                <span class="right btn-arrow-right">right</span>
                <span class="down  btn-arrow-down">down</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page w">
                <span class="up btn-arrow-up">up</span>
                <span class="left btn-arrow-left">left</span>
                <span class="right btn-arrow-right">right</span>
                <span class="down  btn-arrow-down">down</span>
        </div>
        <div class="page s">
           <span class="up btn-arrow-up">up</span>
            <span class="left btn-arrow-left">left</span>
            <span class="right btn-arrow-right">right</span>
            <span class="down  btn-arrow-down">down</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
            <div class="page x">
                    <span class="up btn-arrow-up">up</span>
                    <span class="left btn-arrow-left">left</span>
                    <span class="right btn-arrow-right">right</span>
                    <span class="down  btn-arrow-down">down</span>
        </div>
        <div class="page e">
                <span class="up btn-arrow-up">up</span>
                <span class="left btn-arrow-left">left</span>
                <span class="right btn-arrow-right">right</span>
                <span class="down  btn-arrow-down">down</span>
        </div>
        <div class="page d">
                <span class="up btn-arrow-up">up</span>
                <span class="left btn-arrow-left">left</span>
                <span class="right btn-arrow-right">right</span>
                <span class="down  btn-arrow-down">down</span>
        </div>
        <div class="page c">
                <span class="up btn-arrow-up">up</span>
                <span class="left btn-arrow-left">left</span>
                <span class="right btn-arrow-right">right</span>
                <span class="down  btn-arrow-down">down</span>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. The keyframes for the move-down class were the wrong way around. It should start at -100vh and end at 0vh.
2. The `animationend` listeners remained, so the listener for the move-up would fire even if the move-down was played.

```js
var down = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-arrow-down");
// var container= document.getElementsByClassName("container");
for (var i = 0; i < down.length; i++) {
    down[i].onclick = function showNext(){
        var parent = this.parentElement;
        var ourCont=parent.parentElement;
        var nextCont=ourCont.nextElementSibling;
        var pageToShow=nextCont.firstElementChild;
        var contToMove=ourCont.parentElement;
        
        function animationEnded(){
           contToMove.classList.remove('page-moveUp');
           parent.classList.remove('page-visible');
           contToMove.removeEventListener('animationend',animationEnded);
        }
        contToMove.addEventListener('animationend',animationEnded);
              
        pageToShow.classList.add('page-visible');
        contToMove.classList.add('page-moveUp');
        
    }
}

var up = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-arrow-up");

for (var i = 0; i < up.length; i++) {
    up[i].onclick = function showLast(){        
        var parent = this.parentElement;
        var ourCont=parent.parentElement;
        var lastCont=ourCont.previousElementSibling;
        var pageToShow=lastCont.firstElementChild;
        var contToMove=ourCont.parentElement;
        
        function animationEnded(){
           contToMove.classList.remove('page-moveDown');
           parent.classList.remove('page-visible');
            contToMove.removeEventListener('animationend',animationEnded);
        }
        contToMove.addEventListener('animationend',animationEnded);
      
        contToMove.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
        
        
      });
      pageToShow.classList.add('page-visible');
      contToMove.classList.add('page-moveDown');   
    
              
    }
    
    
     
}
```

```css
body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    
}

.container{   
    display: flex;   
}
.page{  
    min-width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100vh; 
    position: relative;  
    display: none;
}
.page-visible {
    display: block;
  }
.q{
    background:purple;
}
.a{
    background:orange;
}
.z{
    background:red;
}
.w{
    background:brown;
}
.s{
    background:green;
}
.x{
    background:gray;
}
.e{
    background:rgb(42, 165, 83);
}
.d{
    background:rgb(91, 139, 91);
}
.c{
    background:rgb(168, 37, 37);
}
.page-moveUp {
    animation: moveUp 3s ease both;
  }
  @keyframes moveUp {
 from {top:0px }
 to {transform: translateY(-100vh); }
}
.page-moveDown{
    animation: moveDown 3s ease both;
}
@keyframes moveDown {
 from{ transform: translateY(-100vh); }
 to {transform: translateY(0); }
}
.up{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 47%;  
}
.down{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50px;
    left: 47%;
}
.left{
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 50px;

}
.right{
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;;
    right: 50px;  

}
span{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="super-container">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page q page-visible">
            <span class="up btn-arrow-up">up</span>
            <span class="left btn-arrow-left">left</span>
            <span class="right btn-arrow-right">right</span>
            <span class="down  btn-arrow-down">down</span>
        </div>
        <div class="page a">
                <span class="up btn-arrow-up">up</span>
                <span class="left btn-arrow-left">left</span>
                <span class="right btn-arrow-right">right</span>
                <span class="down  btn-arrow-down">down</span>
        </div>
        <div class="page z">
                <span class="up btn-arrow-up">up</span>
                <span class="left btn-arrow-left">left</span>
                <span class="right btn-arrow-right">right</span>
                <span class="down  btn-arrow-down">down</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page w">
                <span class="up btn-arrow-up">up</span>
                <span class="left btn-arrow-left">left</span>
                <span class="right btn-arrow-right">right</span>
                <span class="down  btn-arrow-down">down</span>
        </div>
        <div class="page s">
           <span class="up btn-arrow-up">up</span>
            <span class="left btn-arrow-left">left</span>
            <span class="right btn-arrow-right">right</span>
            <span class="down  btn-arrow-down">down</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
            <div class="page x">
                    <span class="up btn-arrow-up">up</span>
                    <span class="left btn-arrow-left">left</span>
                    <span class="right btn-arrow-right">right</span>
                    <span class="down  btn-arrow-down">down</span>
        </div>
        <div class="page e">
                <span class="up btn-arrow-up">up</span>
                <span class="left btn-arrow-left">left</span>
                <span class="right btn-arrow-right">right</span>
                <span class="down  btn-arrow-down">down</span>
        </div>
        <div class="page d">
                <span class="up btn-arrow-up">up</span>
                <span class="left btn-arrow-left">left</span>
                <span class="right btn-arrow-right">right</span>
                <span class="down  btn-arrow-down">down</span>
        </div>
        <div class="page c">
                <span class="up btn-arrow-up">up</span>
                <span class="left btn-arrow-left">left</span>
                <span class="right btn-arrow-right">right</span>
                <span class="down  btn-arrow-down">down</span>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```